# Unresolved external symbol using MQTT with C++?

Tags: c++, mqtt

I am trying to initialize a client server on my laptop to connect to my raspberry pi using MQTT, i'm using C++ to do this, here is the code I am attempting to do, this is the mqtt.cpp:

```
#include "mqtt.h"
#define PUBLISH_TOPIC "EXAMPLE_TOPIC"

#ifdef DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#endif

mqtt_client::mqtt_client(const char *id, const char *host, int port) : mosquittopp(id)
{
    int keepalive = DEFAULT_KEEP_ALIVE;
    connect(host, port, keepalive);
}

mqtt_client::~mqtt_client()
{
}

void mqtt_client::on_connect(int rc)
{
    if (!rc)
    {
        #ifdef DEBUG
            std::cout << "Connected - code " << rc << std::endl;
        #endif
    }
}

void mqtt_client::on_subscribe(int mid, int qos_count, const int *granted_qos)
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
        std::cout << "Subscription succeeded." << std::endl;
    #endif
}

void mqtt_client::on_message(const struct mosquitto_message *message)
{
    int payload_size = MAX_PAYLOAD + 1;
    char buf[payload_size];

    if(!strcmp(message->topic, PUBLISH_TOPIC))
    {
        memset(buf, 0, payload_size * sizeof(char));

        /* Copy N-1 bytes to ensure always 0 terminated. */
        memcpy(buf, message->payload, MAX_PAYLOAD * sizeof(char));

        #ifdef DEBUG
            std::cout << buf << std::endl;
        #endif

        // Examples of messages for M2M communications...
        if (!strcmp(buf, "STATUS"))
        {
            snprintf(buf, payload_size, "This is a Status Message...");
            publish(NULL, PUBLISH_TOPIC, strlen(buf), buf);
            #ifdef DEBUG
                std::cout << "Status Request Recieved." << std::endl;
            #endif
        }

        if (!strcmp(buf, "ON"))
        {
            snprintf(buf, payload_size, "Turning on...");
            publish(NULL, PUBLISH_TOPIC, strlen(buf), buf);
            #ifdef DEBUG
                std::cout << "Request to turn on." << std::endl;
            #endif
        }

        if (!strcmp(buf, "OFF"))
        {
            snprintf(buf, payload_size, "Turning off...");
            publish(NULL, PUBLISH_TOPIC, strlen(buf), buf);
            #ifdef DEBUG
                std::cout << "Request to turn off." << std:: endl;
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the header mqtt.h:

```
#ifndef SIMPLECLIENT_MQTT_H
#define SIMPLECLIENT_MQTT_H

#include "mosquittopp.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

#define MAX_PAYLOAD 50
#define DEFAULT_KEEP_ALIVE 60

class mqtt_client : public mosqpp::mosquittopp
{
public:
    mqtt_client (const char *id, const char *host, int port);
    ~mqtt_client();

    void on_connect(int rc);
    void on_message(const struct mosquitto_message *message);
    void on_subscribe(int mid, int qos_count, const int *granted_qos);
};

#endif //SIMPLECLIENT_MQTT_H
```

Now, in my main i write the following code:

```
class mqtt_client *iot_client;
int rc;

char client_id[] = CLIENT_ID;
char host[] = BROKER_ADDRESS;
int port = MQTT_PORT;

mosqpp::lib_init();
if (argc > 1)
    strcpy_s(host, argv[1]);

iot_client = new mqtt_client(client_id, host, port);

while (1)
{
    rc = iot_client->loop();
    if (rc)
    {
        iot_client->reconnect();
    }
    else
        iot_client->subscribe(NULL, MQTT_TOPIC);
}

mosqpp::lib_cleanup();
```

after building and compiling, I get 6 "unresolved external symbol" errors, Im not sure why, ive been trying to make this work for 3 days now and no luck. I hope someone with MQTT experience would help me out.

**EDIT**

Here are the errors:

`Severity Code Description  Project File    Line    Suppression State Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl mosqpp::lib_init(void)" (__imp_?lib_init@mosqpp@@YAHXZ) referenced in function main C:\dir\main.obj   1`

`Severity Code Description  Project File Line Suppression State Error LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl mosqpp::lib_cleanup(void)" (__imp_?lib_cleanup@mosqpp@@YAHXZ) referenced in function main IoTSmartTraffic C:\dir\main.obj 1`

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __cdecl mosqpp::mosquittopp::reconnect(void)" (__imp_?reconnect@mosquittopp@mosqpp@@QEAAHXZ) referenced in function main C:\dir\main.obj  1`

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __cdecl mosqpp::mosquittopp::subscribe(int *,char const *,int)" (__imp_?subscribe@mosquittopp@mosqpp@@QEAAHPEAHPEBDH@Z) referenced in function main C:\dir\main.obj   1`

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __cdecl mosqpp::mosquittopp::loop(int,int)" (__imp_?loop@mosquittopp@mosqpp@@QEAAHHH@Z) referenced in function main   C:\dir\main.obj 1`

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl mqtt_client::mqtt_client(char const *,char const *,int)" (??0mqtt_client@@QEAA@PEBD0H@Z) referenced in function main C:\dir\main.obj    1`

Comment: Ok, what operating system, compiler and tools are you using? Which `mqtt` library did you install? How?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Im using visual studio on windows 10, the only library i really could find was this one: github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/tree/master/lib/cpp And the example above is from here: github.com/Auctoris/mosquitopp_client

Comment: Which symbol can it not find?

Comment: edit the question and include them all

Comment: Have you followed the download links at github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/tree/master/lib/cpp and downloaded/installed the package at https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto ? - or have you done something else to get this mqtt library ? Have you then configured your project/solution in  visual studio to link to the mosquitto library ?

Comment: This is a generic cryptic error message from c compilers. It means you are missing some library(es) which contain those functions. I suggest you start googling for those errors and also look for a tutorial to correctly install everything.

Comment: @nos the only libraries in that github for c++ can be found under lib/cpp [here](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/tree/master/lib/cpp) I have included both the cpp file and the header file in my project folder.

Comment: @gorillabull The thing is, i found zero tutorials for MQTT with C++ so every google link has different method, and each method gives me different errors.

Comment: I have found a work around the issue by using the "system()" function in c++ and inside it I would write "mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.x.xx -t topic -m "message" " which works fine, but I would still prefer using the library obviously so if anyone can help, it would be much appreciated. The problem is probably that I am not adding the library correctly but I dont know where to start as there are only 2 files for the cpp library.

Comment: @Abdane I'm asking because it is unknown to everyone you have actually done on your own computer. From what you say now, I can guess that you have included the mosquittopp.cpp and mosquittopp.h in your own project ? If so, then A) That .h file does not support that, it is written for linking to a .dll file.This is the cause of the errors you have now. B) That .cpp file is just a wrapper for the mosquitto C library, so you anyway need to incorporate the entire C library files. So you have to build the .lib and .dll files seperatly, or use the ones in the download link I mentioned.